# Python add a leading zero to column with str and int

Tags: python, pandas

Hello I want to add a leading zero in my current column with str and int but I do not know how.  I only want to add leading zeros to the numbers ex: not A111.  The data is imported from a csv file.  I am very new to pandas and python.

ex:

```
Section
1
2
3
4
4SS
15
S1
A111
```

Convert into:

```
Section
01
02
03
04
4SS
15
S1
A111
```

Comment: is your data a string? or a row?

Comment: Rule of thumb here: post some sample code or at least explain the data structures you're using. That printout isn't useful.

Comment: look into `str.zfill()`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [`str.zfill`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.zfill.html):

```
#numeric as string
df = pd.DataFrame({'Section':['1', '2', '3', '4', 'SS', '15', 'S1', 'A1']})

df['Section'] = df['Section'].str.zfill(2)
print (df)
  Section
0      01
1      02
2      03
3      04
4      SS
5      15
6      S1
7      A1
```

If mixed `numeric` with `strings` first cast to `string`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Section':[1, 2, 3, 4, 'SS', 15, 'S1', 'A1']})

df['Section'] = df['Section'].astype(str).str.zfill(2)
print (df)
  Section
0      01
1      02
2      03
3      04
4      SS
5      15
6      S1
7      A1
```

Comment: thanks! Thought this post was deleted for some reason

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
df['Section'] = df['Section'].apply(lambda x: x.zfill(2))
```

You get

```
Section
0   01
1   02
2   03
3   04
4   SS
5   15
6   S1
7   A1
```

Comment: @MaxU, right. str.zfill() would be preferable over apply