# Pandas - zfill only numeric values in mixed column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a two columns in my dataframe that contain mixed strings - some are all letters, and some are all digits. I need to pad the digit strings with leading zeroes, but not the letter strings.

Input:

```
    Item
0   571
1   63
2   12345
3   99561
4   lid
5   show
```

Desired output:

```
    Item
0   00571
1   00063
2   12345
3   99561
4   lid
5   show
```

Here's what I've got so far:

```
item_columns = ['Item','Item_num']
for column in item_columns:
    df[column][df[column].notnull()] = df[column].astype(str).str.zfill(5)
```

The output is:

```
    Item
0   00571
1   00063
2   12345
3   99561
4   00lid
5   0show
```

I can't have those leading zeroes on index 4 and 5.
Note: I also need to preserve NaN's so they will load into the database as NULL, that's why I am checking for notnull() before doing the conversion.

Different from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42375068/python-add-a-leading-zero-to-column-with-str-and-int) question because I need to avoid padding the letter strings.

Answer (score 1):

Use can start by selecting rows with digits with `isdecimal`:

```
print(df)
    Item
0    571
1     63
2  12345
3  99561
4    lid
5   show

df['Item'][df['Item'].str.isdecimal()] = df['Item'][df['Item'].str.isdecimal()].str.zfill(5)
print(df)

    Item
0  00571
1  00063
2  12345
3  99561
4    lid
5   show
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. When I try this I get 'ValueError: cannot index with vector containing NA / NaN values'. I am trying to retain the 'NaN' values.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution I landed on. You'd think it would have the same problem as my original solution (leading zeroes on short strings), but it doesn't:

```
df['item'] = df['item'].apply(lambda x: str(x).zfill(5))
```