# pandas dataframe zfill multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How can I apply the zfill to multiple columns in pandas?

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2, 3],[4,5,6], [6,7,8], [11,22,33]], columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])
df[['A','B']].convert_dtypes(convert_string=True)
df[['A','B']] = df[['A','B']].str.apply(lambda x: x.zfill(2))
```

fails with "AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'str'" altough I followed https://stackoverflow.com/a/42375779/5618856

to illustrate: How can I get from
**this**      ...to...............     **that**?

```
A  B  C         A  B  C
 1  2  5       01 02  5
 7 59  2       07 59  2
```

i.e. converting multiple columns to string an add a leading zero (fill 2 digits)

Comment: `df[['A','B']].apply(lambda x: x.str.zfill(2))`

Comment: `df[['A','B']].convert_dtypes(convert_string=True)` does not change the dtype of the columns.

Comment: one can also try `applymap` with formatting : `df[['A','B']].applymap('{:0>2}'.format)`

Answer (score 2):

The answer depends on the used data types by pandas. You can check this printing `df.dtypes`.

---

If all data types are integers, than this will work:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([[1.0, 2, 3],[4,5,6], [6,7,8], [11,22,33]], columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])
df[['A','B']] = df[['A','B']].apply(lambda x: x.astype(str).str.zfill(2))
```

---

If at least on value is of type float, you have to convert the value to an integer first, than to a string and call `zfill()` afterwards.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1.0, 2, 3],[4,5,6], [6,7,8], [11,22,33]], columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])
df.dtypes
df[['A','B']] = df[['A','B']].apply(lambda x: x.astype(int).astype(str).str.zfill(2))
```

---

In both cases the output is

```
    A   B   C
0  01  02   3
1  04  05   6
2  06  07   8
3  11  22  33
```

---

This answer is only an extention of the first one by Mondaa.

Comment: Thanks, I just found this hint with double conversion, too.

Comment: I saw your comment, but was working already on the answer. You are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to assign the new columns to your data frame after changing the column types.
You can change the column types to string by :

```
df[['A','B']] = df[['A','B']].astype(str)
```

Then, use the lambda function to apply the zfill mehtod:

```
df[['A','B']] = df[['A','B']].apply(lambda x: x.str.zfill(2))
```

The output in your input case would be like:

```
    A   B   C
0   01  02  3
1   04  05  6
2   06  07  8
3   11  22  33
```

note: the last row is unaffected as it is already of 2 digit numbers.

Comment: Thanks, this works on the simple example. Applying this to my real dataframe I get 2.0 17.0 23.0 etc. I guess I need to explore it further.

Comment: You have to cast you floats as int first, than you can try this approche again. Hope all your floats ends with an `0`.

Comment: I found this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51325032/converting-exponential-notation-numbers-to-strings-explanation where the reason is that pandas makes an educated guess on csv read data. Later a double conversion `astype('int64').astype(str)` can fix this. Not pretty but works.